# How to create individual email id to users on my domain through rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I would like to create an email service for all the users on my site, for example: abc@xyz.com, where users will be able to send and receive personalized emails. To start I only need to be able to send and receive emails in Rails.

Users need to be able to register an email at xyz.com and to send and receive emails from xyz.com.

Are there any solutions already available in Rails? Is there any gem or plugin that do this?

If I need to start from scratch, any resource that might helpful for solving the problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store these users in a SQL database, perhaps you can configure an MTA and an IMAP server to use your Rails database as the user database, then use Squirrelmail or any other web mail client to provide the e-mail user interface.

I believe both Dovecot IMAP server and the Postfix MTA can use MySQL or PostgreSQL to lookup/authenticate users.

There seems to be a webmail app in Rails http://mailr.org/.